# jpql Join query

Tags: jsf, join, ejb-3.0, jpql

i have an association table called MenuPrevilege between 2 tables called Menu and Previlege.
In order to get all menus of a specific previlege i created a named query in the Menu entity:

```
   @Entity
   @NamedQueries( {
   @NamedQuery(name = "getAllMenus", query = "select m from Menu m"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "getMenusByPrevilegeId", query = "select m from Menu m
            JOIN m.menuPrevilege mp where mp.previlege_id = :p")})


public class Menu implements Serializable {

private String url;
private String description;
private List<MenuPrevilege> menuPrevilges;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Menu() {
    super();
}

@Id
public String getUrl() {
    return this.url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setMenuPrevilges(List<MenuPrevilege> menuPrevilges) {
    if (menuPrevilges == null)
        menuPrevilges = new ArrayList<MenuPrevilege>();
    this.menuPrevilges = menuPrevilges;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
public List<MenuPrevilege> getMenuPrevilges() {
    if (menuPrevilges == null)
        menuPrevilges = new ArrayList<MenuPrevilege>();
    return menuPrevilges;
}

public Menu(String url, String description) {
    super();
    this.url = url;
    this.description = description;
}
    }
```

i'm having this exception org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:menuPrevilege , and i don't know how to deal with it. this is the MenuPrevilege entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Menu_Previlege")

    public class MenuPrevilege implements Serializable {

private IdMenuPrevilege idmenuPrevilege = new IdMenuPrevilege();
private Date activationDate;
private Date deactivationDate;
private Menu menu;
private Previlege previlege;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MenuPrevilege() {
    super();
}

@EmbeddedId
public IdMenuPrevilege getIdmenuPrevilege() {
    return this.idmenuPrevilege;
}

public void setIdmenuPrevilege(IdMenuPrevilege idmenuPrevilege) {
    this.idmenuPrevilege = idmenuPrevilege;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getActivationDate() {
    return this.activationDate;
}

public void setActivationDate(Date activationDate) {
    this.activationDate = activationDate;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getDeactivationDate() {
    return this.deactivationDate;
}

public void setDeactivationDate(Date deactivationDate) {
    this.deactivationDate = deactivationDate;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Menu getMenu() {
    return menu;
}

public void setPrevilege(Previlege previlege) {
    this.previlege = previlege;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "previlege_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Previlege getPrevilege() {
    return previlege;
}

public MenuPrevilege(Menu menu, Previlege previlege) {
    super();
    getIdmenuPrevilege().setIdMenu(menu.getUrl());
    getIdmenuPrevilege().setIdPrevilege(previlege.getPrevilegeId());
    this.setMenu(menu);
    this.setPrevilege(previlege);
    menu.getMenuPrevilges().add(this);
    previlege.getPrevilegeMenus().add(this);
}

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made name refactoring  to my code edit my query and everything seems to be working. Here are the changes :

1. in the named query:

   ```
   @NamedQuery(name = "getMenusByPrevilegeId", query = "select m from Menu m  JOIN 
    m.previleges p where p.previlege.previlegeId = :p")})
   ```
2. the entity attribute

   ```
   private List<MenuPrevilege> previleges;
   // getters and setters as well
   ```
3. in the constructor of the MenuPrevilege entity

   ```
   public MenuPrevilege(Menu menu, Previlege previlege) {
   super();
   getIdmenuPrevilege().setIdMenu(menu.getUrl());
   getIdmenuPrevilege().setIdPrevilege(previlege.getPrevilegeId());
   this.setMenu(menu);
   this.setPrevilege(previlege);
   menu.getPrevileges().add(this);
   previlege.getMenus().add(this);
   }
   ```

as u can notice it was a syntax error in my query that caused the exception.